# Backing up Macintosh HD via Disk Utility (error -5344)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, disk-utility, recovery

I am trying to backup the Macintosh HD, to my external hard drive via disk utility. I created a blank image and tried to restored my MacintoshHD to that image, but the error pops up, "Restore Failure: error -5344"

Any help on how can I proceed with the backup?

Comment: What do you have against Time Machine?

Comment: Im in recovery mode.

Comment: @ritvik1512 if it is the same computer, you may add a link to the other questions to add relevant context information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two Machintosh HDs together, choose the second (indented) one. You may need to unlock it via the context menu.

Then tell Disk Utility to create an image of the volume directly. In Disk Utility with the `Macintosh HD` volume selected, use `New disk image` on the toolbar or select `New` > `Disk Image from "Macintosh HD"` from the `File` menu.

Bear in mind that the created image has all of the problems from the original filesystem, and the creation of the image may fail if there are underlying I/O errors.

You could instead install the OS on the external drive and manually copy what you need to keep. If you get an error (usually -36 or -50), divide the problematic set in half and keep copying until you've either found a set of files you don't care about or narrowed it down to the exact things that have errors and have to be skipped.

If you need applications that weren't just dragged to /Applications, use the migration assistant, and hope it doesn't hit something that won't copy.